# Where to ask Pandoc questions?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

Where should I ask a question about Pandoc that isn't TeX-/LaTeX-specific?

Examples:

- > #### Can I specify command line options in a Pandoc Markdown document?
  >
  > Sometimes, a `*.md` file requires (due to its content) a certain set of command line options regardless of the desired output or of
  >   other, more optional command line options.
  >   E.g. when the document contains pandoc-fignos-style figure markup, `--filter pandoc-fignos` will always be required when wanting
  >   meaningful non-intermediate output.
  >
  > Instead of having to remember which of my Pandoc documents requires what options, can I declare arbitrary command line options within the
  >   file itself, e.g. inside the YAML metadata? Or is there a
  >   corresponding metadatafield for each and every option that I could
  >   set instead. (If the latter, how can I find out about those field,
  >   e.g., what would be the corresponding field to `--filter`?)
  >
  > #### Tags
  >
  > [pandoc](/questions/tagged/pandoc) [pandoc-markdown](/questions/tagged/pandoc-markdown) [pandoc-yaml-metadata](/questions/tagged/pandoc-yaml-metadata) [cli](/questions/tagged/cli)
- > #### Can I specify multiple bibliography (BibTeX) files in Pandoc Metadata?
  >
  > Often, journal websites and other sources offer downloadable `*.bib` files for referring to individual articles. If I use these, I like to keep them as they are instead of merging them into a single file.
  >   On the command line, several files can be specified by passing the `--bibliography` option multiple times. Can I also list multiple files in the YAML metadata inside the document itself?
  >
  > #### Tags
  >
  > [pandoc](/questions/tagged/pandoc) [pandoc-markdown](/questions/tagged/pandoc-markdown) [pandoc-yaml-metadata](/questions/tagged/pandoc-yaml-metadata) [pandoc-citeproc](/questions/tagged/pandoc-citeproc)

(The latter question isn't LaTeX specific AFAIK, as pandoc-citeproc will process references and `*.bib` files even for inputs/outputs that don't to through LaTeX for processing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like programming. There's nearly [a thousand Pandoc questions at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandoc).

I only see a [handful of questions on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=pandoc+-site%3Astackoverflow.com+-site%3Atex.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you! Although I somewhat disagree that this "sounds like programming", I'm following the lead of those who've asked before me and have asked this questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43629039/674064) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43629349/674064). The first one actually already has some potential duplicates on [SO].